# Sum of two Columns in a Table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My assignment is that i have Three columns `Stock_Opening`,`Stock_New`,`Stock_Available` apart from P_Key and F_key.I have to insert some value in `Stock_New`. Then `Stock_Opening` + `Stock_New` will add up and value will go into `Stock_Available`

Problem:When i insert a value in `Stock_New` and execute it only update `Stock_New`
if i again execute same query it now update both tables `Stock_New` with current 
 value and `Stock_Available` with previous value.
I want that `Stock_New` and `Stock_Available` update simultaneously 
Bellow is Query that i m executing

```
UPDATE Stock
SET Stock_New = Stock_New + '2',
    Stock_Available = Stock_Opening + Stock_New
WHERE Med_ID = 'PANAD223'
```

Bellow are Screenshots linearly

[image: This is the table before execution]

[image: This is the table after first execution]

[image: This is the table after second execution]

Comment: Rather than screenshots, post your code as `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have `stock_available = stock_opening + stock_new + 2` as SQL counts the first value, not the updated one.

An easier way do it is to create the column Stock_Available as computed from the other two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE Stock
DROP COLUMN Stock_Available

ALTER TABLE Stock
ADD Stock_Available AS Stock_New + Stock_Opening
```

Now you only have to do an update:

```
UPDATE Stock Set Stock_New = Stock_New + 2 WHERE Med_ID='PANAD223'
```

and Stock_Available will automatically update

Comment: I want something like you  suggested,Someone bellow shared an article about computed column specification and it described as virtual column.This term confuses me.can i use `SELECT` with this column and like that?

Comment: You can Select the column, do a total on it if you like. You can not INSERT or UPDATE a computed column, mainly because you don't have to. SQL does the job for you, it automatically sums the other two columns and you only need to update/insert Stock_New and Stock_Opening. Every time Stock_New or Stock_Opening are updated, Stock_Available will also be updated.

Answer (score 1):

`Stock_New` is updated with latest value after `update` is finished. Try:

```
UPDATE Stock SET Stock_New = Stock_New + 2 , Stock_Available = Stock_Opening + Stock_New+2 WHERE Med_ID='PANAD223'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to a column in an `UPDATE` you get the value **before** the `UPDATE`. So `Stock_New` is always two short in `Stock_Available = Stock_Opening + Stock_New`. You need to add the `2` there too.

```
UPDATE stock
       SET stock_new = stock_new + 2,
           stock_available = stock_opening + stock_new + 2
       WHERE med_id = 'PANAD223';
```

Also, if you have number literals, don't enclose them in single quotes. That's for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update like below:

```
UPDATE Stock SET Stock_New = Stock_New + '2', Stock_Available = Stock_Opening + Stock_New + '2' WHERE Med_ID='PANAD223'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, computed columns fits better in your case.

> Computed columns actually are virtual columns that are not physically
>   stored in the table unless the column is marked PERSISTED. Values for
>   computed columns are recalculated every time they are referenced in a
>   query

see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/computed-columns-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

when you data update 1, Stock_New=28, Stock_Opening=20

```
UPDATE Stock SET Stock_New = 28 + '2', 
                 Stock_Available = 20 + 28
 WHERE Med_ID='PANAD223'
```

when you data update 2, Stock_New=30, Stock_Opening=20

```
UPDATE Stock SET Stock_New = 28 + '2', 
                 Stock_Available = 20 + 30
 WHERE Med_ID='PANAD223'
```

So you add  (+ '2') to

```
UPDATE Stock SET Stock_New = Stock_New + '2', 
                 Stock_Available = Stock_Opening + Stock_New + '2'
 WHERE Med_ID='PANAD223'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc sampleupdate
as
begin
declare @stocknew int,
declare @stockopening int 

set @stocknew=(select Stock_New from Stock (condition))
set @stockopening=(select Stock_Opening  from Stock (condition))

set @stocknew=@stocknew +'2'
UPDATE Stock SET Stock_New =@sn, Stock_Available = @stockopening + @sn WHERE 
Med_ID='PANAD223'
end
```

Comment: better to go for stored procedure,data type may vary

Answer (score 0):

Trying to calculate the Stock_Available field in the same Update statement where you assign a new value to Stock_New, it will use the stored value of Stock_New instead of the calculated (updated) value. So Stock_Available will always be 2 less than it's supposed to be. You can add a +2 to the Stock_Available calculation like others have answered, or you can run two separate Update statements.

Update statement #1 sets the new Stock_New value:

```
UPDATE Stock
SET Stock_New = Stock_New + 2
WHERE Med_ID = 'PANAD223';
```

Once Stock_New has it's new value, use that new value to calculate Stock_Available:

```
UPDATE Stock
SET Stock_Available = Stock_Opening + Stock_New
WHERE Med_ID = 'PANAD223'
```